# if Schema-Registry is down, does that mean Kafka will have downtime?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

So there is a Kafka cluster and we have a Schema registry on top of it to validate schema for topics. For some maintenance reason if schema registry is down, Kafka will have downtime for that duration and it will not accept any new incoming data request ?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka consumers and producers cache the schemas they retrieve from the schema registry internally. The Schema Registry is only contacted when a record is sent/received for which no schema was previously seen.

So as long as you don't start any new consumers/producers or send records with schemas that have not been previously sent you should be fine.

Take this with a grain of salt though, I've looked through the code and run a quick test with the console consumer and producer and could still produce and consume after killing the schema registry, but there may be cases where it still fails.

**Update:**

It occurred to me today that I probably have answered your question too literal, instead of trying to understand what you are trying to do :)

If you want to enable maintenance windows on your schema registry, it might be worthwhile looking into running two or more schema registries in parallel and configure both of them in your producers and consumers.
One of them will be elected master and write requests for schemas will be forwarded to that instance. That way you can perform rolling restarts if you need maintenance windows.

Answer (score 0):

The `KafkaAvroSerializer` and deserializer maintain a schema ID cache.

So as long as no new producers and consumers come online, you would see no errors.

If the registry was down, Kafka will not have downtime, but you will start to see network exception errors in the clients since they use HTTP to talk to the registry whereas Kafka uses its own TCP protocol